# What are some easy non-expensive ways to clean a toilet?

Tags: cleaning

In particular, the exterior of a toilet.

My parents tell me to wipe the outside and surrounding floor of the toilet with a diaper several times (and then to wash the diaper with water in the sink several times). I'm really not sure if this is the most time-efficient way to clean the exterior of a toilet, and I'm not sure if it's the cleanest way to clean the exterior of a toilet either. Plus, the sink might get clogged with all the debris.

Something eco-friendly would be preferable if possible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put 1/3 vinegar, 2/3 water in a reusable spray container (you can buy unused ones at many hardware stores and gardening supply stores).

Spray the exterior of the toilet, then wipe with whatever you want to use. You could use a couple of hand towels, cloth diapers, whatever.

The vinegar is a good disinfectant and is very eco-friendly. Toss the cloths into the laundry and wash normally. The vinegar should prevent any nasties from growing for a day or so. If no one is making a huge mess around the toilet (like a potty-training child), you only need to clean it once a week, so just plan to clean it the day before you usually do laundry.

Answer (score 0):

Paper towels and or toilet paper. Mixed with some kind of surface cleaner and water. You also get toilet brushes for the inside of it.

Fun Fact: There is more germs on your money, light switches and computer keyboard than there is on a toilet seat :)

Answer (score -2):

Try putting some mouth wash around the edges of the toilet before you flush. This is a last option. Do not use this as your first option. I am serious!

Comment: What does this do, and why should it be the last option?

Comment: We gotta do something about the necro-threads.  This is from May 9 (and answered same day).

Comment: @dbracey that concept doesn't exist here. Users are always welcome to add new answers to old questions. We even have badges to reward people for it.

Comment: I'm interested in helping people that post questions, not creating the false impression of activity.